# Cardinality of a subset having all the elements with order $5$ of a group

Tags: group-theory

If order of a group $G$ is $20$ and $H$ is a subset of $G$ which contains all elements of $G$ having order $5$. Then what is the order of subset H?
$a) 4  \ \  b) 8   \ \  c) 12   \ \ d) 16.$

Since 5 is prime so H would have $4K$ elements, where $K$ is some natural number. But this would be applicable if H is a subgroup.
I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you know Sylow's theorems?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: yes, I know sylow theorems. The group G has sylow 2- subgroups of order 4.

Comment: What's $H$ specifically? $G$ and the set of all elements having order $5$ can be $H$.

Comment: H = { a belong to G| a^5= e, a is not e } where e is identity of group.

Comment: @Mathsaddict What about Sylow subgroups of order $5$?

Comment: group G has one sylow subgroup of order 5.